# Add separate domain name to Wordpress admin area with htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, wordpress

I have a Wordpress installation in a seperate folder on my server (meaning it is not in the root folder). Let's call that folder "folder A". I have a htaccess rewrite rule that maps Domain A to folder A. Inside folder A is the Wordpress admin folder, let's call it folder A.B. I tried mapping Domain B to folder A.B., but I can't get it to work properly. When you log in to Wordpress via /admin, you get redirected to /wp-login.php (so from folder A.B. to folder A), maybe that is where I get into trouble. So what I would like to do is this:

Domain A > folder A 
Domain B > folder A.B

Note that this is not for security purposes, I just like the idea of www.domainb.com instead of www.domaina.com/wp-admin. Can this be done with Wordpress?

Comment: ` Can this be done with Wordpress?` No, this can't be done with WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

That is the problem with Wordpress where the installation to Domain A would take over before you ever come to the DomainA,B Wordpress installation because of the Wordpress mod_rewrite rules inside the .htaccess file.

Can you answer why would you use such setup, to have a Wordpress installation inside a Wordpress installation ?

It would be far more logical to have separate installations, for example:
public_html/domaina.com/
public_html/domainb.com/

Are you using cPanel for this installation?

Comment: I am not really having a Wordpress installation inside another, there is only one Wordpress install. It's just that I would like to seperate the front from the backend for some users who will only be using the backend admin area. I am indeed using cPanel.